# How do I enable materialized views in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

```
create materialized view if not exists s.emp
as
select id, count(name) as count from employee primary key (name);
```

Query 1 ERROR: Materialized views are disabled. Enable in cassandra.yaml to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked!

open the **cassandra.yaml** file, in mac if you have installed cassandra using

**brew install cassandra**

go to path **/usr/local/etc/cassandra** will find the cassandra.yaml file. Search for materialized view in that file.

and in place of

> enable_materialized_views: false

by default will be false, change it to true

> enable_materialized_views: true

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to add the following line to `cassandra.yaml` to enable materialised views:

```
materialized_views_enabled: true
```

You will need to enable it on all nodes of the cluster then perform a rolling restart for the change to take effect.

Note that MVs are considered experimental which is why they are disabled by default. Be aware of the pros and cons of MVs before using it in production as I've discussed in this post -- https://community.datastax.com/articles/2774/.

For more information on the experimental status of materialised views, see the entries in [NEWS.txt](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.0.3/NEWS.txt#L347-L356) on Github. Cheers!

Comment: where can i find the cassandra.yaml file

Comment: It's in the `conf/` directory. Cheers!

Comment: in yaml file if i enable materialized view getting an exception while restarting cassandra

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: @ErickRamirez You said: `There are some improvements and fixes coming in Cassandra 4.0` in your blog. So is it now ok to use materialized_views in production? I've cassandra 4.0.7.

Comment: In Docker image this file path is: `/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml`

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to ***/etc/cassandra***

Open and edit file: **cassandra.yaml**  , you can use command ***"nano cassandra.yaml"***

search for **materialized_views_enabled: false** and set it to **true**. By default, its usually near the bottom of the file.